# rate link-ways to perform

Tags: objective-c

I can see that there are many ways to write the url for rating the app,
my way is :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appName/id-----------?mt=8"]];
```

i saw many other ways like :

```
@"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=341086403";
```

i cant check that, and i want to be sure.
whats the way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what your question is here. You are using **`openURL`** correctly to redirect the user to the App Store. iOS will parse this URL, see that its an iTunes app link and redirect the user accordingly.

Also, the Second example you posted is to redirect the user to the Customer Reviews page for the app.

Comment: ok thanks, my goal is to redirect the user to rate my app and not only to the app page(i know my url is taking the user to the app page) so, what should i use ??

Comment: actually after i have checked, i have to use the second one ! the first takes you to the app page and not to the reviews page.

Answer (score 1):

Use Appirater classes to rate your app.I hope  [this](http://www.buzztouch.com/forum/thread.php?tid=B60C6EE41CD7D289048B0F4)  link will help you.

Comment: thanks i did that algorithm by my self to check num of operations.